# What is get used for in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Code: https://github.com/acani/Chats/blob/master/Chats/Chats/ChatViewController.swift

The `inputAccessoryView` method uses `get { }`. Any reason why?

If I put a "println" on the line before `get`, it says `use of unresolved identifier 'get'`. I'm trying to see if the code before `get` is being called because the `println` I have inside is not being called.

What exactly is `get` used for here?

Comment: I'd bet it's defining a getter method. but why not read a basic Swift tutorial?

Comment: Lookup "Computed Properties" in the Swift reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_380) in the reference. Scroll down to "Computed Properties".

> In addition to stored properties, classes, structures, and enumerations can define computed properties, which do not actually store a value. Instead, they provide a getter and an optional setter to retrieve and set other properties and values indirectly.

So that syntax lets the value returned by a property to be caluclated on the value rather than just fetching a value. Code other than a `get` or `set` block in a property definition is not valid, which is why you get that error.